# Association bonus given without point requirement reached

Tags: bug, reputation

[This user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/895424/old-planar) has only one post, with only two upvotes, and $121$ reputation. I was wondering how that could be, so I looked at their [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/895424/old-planar?tab=reputation), which says that they received the association bonus. This does not make sense to me, since they only have accounts here and on MO, and only have one post between the two accounts. Also, their account was created today, so it's not possible to have earned a bunch of points and then deleted their posts.

Is this a bug? Or is there some other requirement for this bonus I am not aware of? There are other instances of association bonus bugs discussed on meta, but those all seem to be delays in getting the bonus, or getting it slightly early, not $180$ points early.

Comment: This account looks really old, the network ID starts with 5... This may justify the association bonus. Secondly, I ran a SEDE query and found that the user created another account and deleted it at rep 126--> https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1089480/list-of-communities-of-an-user-included-the-hidden-ones?NetworkAccountId=851

Comment: User have the option of hiding their communities. That's might be why.

Comment: @ArcticChar that's certainly possible, but not the case here.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi this link is better, because it immediately runs it for the user in question: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1089480/list-of-communities-of-an-user-included-the-hidden-ones?NetworkAccountId=512468 - the account with 126 reputation is their current Math.SE account.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yup, the link. But, the account is not their current acc. Look at the account number [890102](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/890102?tab=topactivity) instead of *895424*

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi ah, well spotted!